# UncaughtExceptionHandler in tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, out-of-memory

I'm getting OutOfMemoryError in tomcat source while executing my web application.

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at com.source.server.wc.common.SupportAction.execute(SupportAction.java:252)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.source.server.wc.common.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.source.server.wc.common.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have added 
**Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new OOMEHandler());**    in my main Thread, Now I'm getting OOMError while executing task from webclient, but OOMError not catched by the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

How can i catch it?

Comment: Are you sure that the same thread for which you invoked `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is also the thread that experienced the `OutOfMemoryError`? Remember that Tomcat uses thread pools; depending on how your request/response cycle is designed, it's possible that theses end up being two different threads.

Comment: Also java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is a Error which is subtype of Throwable. I think only Exception types will trigger UncaughtExceptionHandler. Try throwing a RunTimeException to see if this is true.

Comment: @Isaac I've added the exception trace, and not sure about whether OutOfMemoryError experienced in the same thread or not. if the thread invoked by tomcat then how can i catch OutOfMemoryError ?

Comment: OK, now add `new RuntimeException().printStackTrace()` after `Thread.currentThread().set....`, and by comparing the stack traces, you'll be able to see whether both originate in the same thread.

Comment: new RuntimeException().printStackTrace() gives me a trace from where the jvm iinvoked ie)I've set Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new OOMEHandler()); in main class itself, and The same thread invokes new thread to start the tomcat server by invoking org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

`UncaughtExceptionHandler` will also catch the `OutOfMemoryError`. You seem to be setting it correclty. So either some other process is calling it afterwards (you can check by setting a breakpoint of the function), or TomCat has one of its own that is set on your `Thread`, you can check that by calling `Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. This will return `null` if none is set.

Also note that `setDefaultExceptionHandler()` is static, so you should not call it on an object instead on the class, so:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new OOMEHandler());
```

instead of

```
Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new OOMEHandler());
```

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler() returns java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]

Comment: I made a mistake in the answer, will fix it. This means there is none set, so (if available) the default will be called. This probably means you are calling it on the wrong thread. Is there any of your own code in the stacktrace you posted (it looks like there isn't)

Comment: com.source.server.wc.common.SupportAction.execute   is my own code which is a webclient class extends Action

Comment: If the result you just posted is from that function, then your defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler will be called. (to verify you can try `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to see noone unset yours). Note that `OutOfMemoryException` is one with weird side effects because if you try to create many new objects in your handler it will be thrown again (and not be caught). So in general the first thing you should do is log it. Another way to test it works correctly is to just throw an exception of your own `throw new Exception("testing handler")`.